# Force xslt document() to load an external document over HTTP rather than directly from the file system

Tags: .net, asp.net, xml, xslt

Within my ASP.NET application, I'm loading an XML file into an XSLT with the `document()` method, as follows:

```
<xsl:variable name="more-xml" select="document('generateXml.ashx')" />
```

This works fine when I run it locally, but fails when I deploy it to the server because the server finds `generateXml.ashx` through the file system, so it isn't processed by IIS.

If I hard-code the URL like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="more-xml" select="document('http://server/app/generateXml.ashx')" />
```

Then the document address is always resolved over HTTP, so it works consistently - but I don't want to hard-code the URL into the XSLT. Is there a way to force document() to use HTTP instead of FILE for a relative path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of loading the XML with the document() method within the XSLT, use an `XmlArgumentsList` to populate an `<xsl:param>` with the XML.

```
XsltArgumentList args = new XsltArgumentList();
args.AddParam("more-xml", string.Empty, myXmlDocument.CreateNavigator().SelectChildren(XPathNodeType.All));

// pass the argument list to the transform
myXslCompiledTransform.Transform(sourceXml, args, myXmlWriter);
```

Then in the XSLT:

```
<xsl:param name="more-xml"></xsl:param>
```